# Can't search MS Access database using LIKE with % or *

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, wildcard, sql-like

I am trying to query a MS Access database from my java code and I am having no luck with the % wildcard that I read should work in other posts. The LIKE operator works if I exclude the wild cards from my code and provide the searchText variable with a value that matches exactly to a records Description. Below is the String queries I have tried that have either returned null or an exception:

String tableName = "SSPWO";
      String desc = "[Description]";

```
  String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE " + desc + " LIKE '%" searchText +  "%' ORDER BY [WorkOrderNo] DESC", tableName);
```

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

String tableName = "SSPWO";
      String desc = "[Description]";

```
  String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE " + desc + " LIKE '*" searchText +  "*' ORDER BY [WorkOrderNo] DESC", tableName);
```

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

String tableName = "SSPWO";
      String desc = "[Description]";

```
  String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE " + desc + " LIKE \"%" searchText +  "%\" ORDER BY [WorkOrderNo] DESC", tableName);
```

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

String tableName = "SSPWO";
      String desc = "[Description]";

```
  String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE " + desc + " LIKE \'%" searchText +  "%\' ORDER BY [WorkOrderNo] DESC", tableName);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't just say "null or an exception": Post the stack traces for each of the failing cases. (Also, you should use prepared statements instead of string pasting to construct queries.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent sign (`%`) is definitely the right wildcard character to use in this case. For test data

```
ID  Description                        
--  -----------------------------------
 1  I like apple pie.                  
 2  This is a test.                    
 3  Apple makes iThings.               
 4  This is another test.              
 5  Name of a tropical fruit: pineapple
```

the code

```java
String tableName = "SSPWO"; 
String desc = "[Description]";
String searchText = "apple";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
        String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s LIKE ?", tableName, desc)
        );
ps.setString(1, "%" + searchText + "%");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%d: %s", rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2)));
}
```

produces the following console output

```
1: I like apple pie.
3: Apple makes iThings.
5: Name of a tropical fruit: pineapple
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. The prepared statement was definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a whack of syntax errors anyways:

```
String query = String.format([..snip...] + " LIKE '%" searchText 
                                                     ^---missing +
```